# Absolutely integrable function not of exponential order

Tags: laplace-transform

Construct an example of a continuous function $y=f(x)$ defined on $[0,\infty)$, such that it is absolutely integrable, i.e.,

$\int^\infty_0 |f(x)|dx<\infty$,

but not of exponential order.

What about a function of exponential order?

For reference "A real function $y=f(x)$ on $[0,\infty)$ or $(0,\infty)$ is defined to be of exponential order $u $ if there are constants $u\geq 0$, $M\geq 0$, and $A\geq 0$ , such that $|f(x)|\leq Me^{ux},$ for all $x\in[A,\infty)$

It seems to me that any old function that is continuous ought to be of exponential order so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: How about we multiply $e^{x^2}$ by a characteristic function whose support is unbounded, but sufficiently sparse to keep the integral finite? The result isn't continuous, but this can be mollified as well.

Comment: i don't think it is possible to create such a function , maybe if it was discontinuous at countably infinite points maybe , but this i dont think so

Comment: @EugeneShvarts how do u keep it finite ?

Comment: @EugeneShvarts $e^{x^2}$ is not of exponential order and I also don't see how to keep it finite.

Comment: Eugene's idea almost works, except that you get a discontinuous function. You can instead take a function that is zero everywhere except for small intervals around the integer numbers in which the graph looks like a triangle, and such that equals $e^{x^2}$ for $x$ integer. The sizes of the bases of the triangles can be adjusted (decrease to zero really fast), for example $1/n^2e^{n^2}$ such that the integral converges.

Comment: @avz2611 e.g., in the interval $(n,n+1)$, let the support be contained in an interval with length $e^{-(n+1)^2}/n^2$. I thought the goal is to find a function not of exponential order? If we are allowed exponential order, there isn't much to do -- just take a Gaussian bump or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can build such a function as follows: As we want $f$ not to be of exponential order, we will choose $f$ such that 
$$ f(n) = n\exp(nx), \qquad n \in \mathbb N $$
Then $f$ is not of exponential order. To make $f$ absolutely integrable, define $a_n := (1+n)^{-2}\exp(-2nx)$, then $f(n)a_n \to 0$ and define $f$ by 
$$
  f(x) := \begin{cases} n\exp(nx)\frac 1{a_n}(x-n+a_n) & x \in [n - a_n, n]\\
                       -n\exp(nx)\frac 1{a_n}(x-n-a_n) & x \in [n, n+a_n]\\
                       0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$
Then $f$ is continous, and we have 
$$ \int_0^K f(x)\, dx \le \sum_{k=0}^{\lceil K\rceil}
       k\exp(kx) \cdot \frac 12 \cdot 2a_k
   \le \sum_{k=0}^{\lceil K \rceil} (1+k)^{-1}\exp(-kx) \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty (1+k)^{-1}\exp(-kx) < \infty.
$$